# Adjust width of box in Calendar based on content

Tags: javascript, jquery, adminlte

I am currently working on draggable events on Calendar using the [ADMIN LTE Template](https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/pages/calendar.html)

[image]

**How do I resize the calendar box width based on the length on the string of the item inside?**

Comment: You can go with the flex-box approach and also set a max-width of the columns if possible.

Answer (score 0):

use "width: fit-content;"

Comment: Please add more information in your answer, like how this would solve the issue, etc.